# Update user meta data after Woocommerce new user registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, user-data

Im trying to add a custom field to `WP_USERMETA` table after Woocommerce registration

```
add_filter('woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'wc_assign_custom_role', 10, 1);

function wc_assign_custom_role($args) {
  update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

  return $args;
}
```

as you see Im trying to capture password before hashing and save it in a different hash format in that table

but It doesnt add anything to the table

I tested the same line inside wordpress registration hook `user_register` and it worked but only for wordpress registration not woocommerce

**UPDATE**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_new_customer_data', 'wc_assign_custom_role', 10, 1);

function wc_assign_custom_role($args) {
  global $current_user;
  update_user_meta($current_user->$user_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

  return $args;
}
```

still doesnt work

**UPDATE II**

```
function action_woocommerce_created_customer( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated ) { 
    update_user_meta($customer_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
}; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'action_woocommerce_created_customer', 10, 3 );
```

this one create meta data but it seems it uses different `$_POST['password']` rather than the password I entered, so hash something else rather than password

Any thoughts??

Comment: Where do get `$user_id` from? IMO you need to use the `woocommerce_created_customer` hook, because then WC passes the `$customer_id` to your callback.

Comment: please check the update

Comment: so whats the equivalent to user_register hook? because in that hook I was able to use $_POST method to get the raw format of password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution, We should use `$_POST['account_password']` instead of `$_POST['password']`

```
function action_woocommerce_created_customer( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated ) { 
    update_user_meta($customer_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($_POST['account_password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
}; 

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'action_woocommerce_created_customer', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 3):

When looking at the source code where `woocommerce_created_customer` action hook is located, the password can be found as `$new_customer_data['user_pass']` *(see at the end of the answer)*.

So your code should be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'action_woocommerce_created_customer', 10, 3 ); 
function action_woocommerce_created_customer( $customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated ) { 
    update_user_meta($customer_id, 'user_pass2', password_hash($new_customer_data['user_pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

---

Here is the **related source code involved** from `wc_create_new_customer()` function:

```
    $new_customer_data = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_new_customer_data', array(
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_pass'  => $password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'role'       => 'customer',
    ) );
```

and `$_POST['account_password']` is not required as **it's already stored in `$password` variable.**

Comment: Thank you for the detail of $new_customer_data @LoicTheAztec